# Dual ubuntu 16.04 can't mount hard drive after a upgrading Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, mount

My computer are installing Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 in dual. I worked normal on Ubuntu until I came back Windows 10 and got an update/upgrade after 2 months from the last time.
When I back to Ubuntu, I can not mount my hard drive anymore. The error like bellow:
[Can't mount hard drive after upgrading windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T98eE.png)

I already turn off fast boot, hibernate.

Any recommendation is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!!

Comment: The solution to solve my problem is:
1. Move data to another hard drive.
2. Format the drive. Delete all disk on drive. Convert drive to basic drive.
3. Move data back to hard drive

Answer (score 0):

This is [not uncommon after Windows updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows). Try using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from Ubuntu installation USB drive, running from that flash drive.

On occasion, I've found it necessary to reinstall Ubuntu, if Boot-Repair fails:

- Save your current ext4 partition to another disk.
- Reinstall a minimal Ubuntu.
- Overwrite the new installation with that saved.

You might also update to 18.04 LTS; I've had no problems with Windows damaging that version *yet*.